# Brand new create-react-app error when deploying to heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, create-react-app

I'm experimenting with a brand new create-react-app and heroku. Create-react-app works locally. Then I have followed this steps [Heroku link](https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration#create-and-deploy-a-react-app-in-two-minutes).

And when opened Heroku page shows an error like the app couldn't be rendered

Error: Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

Some Log:
2017-08-09T03:05:27.622396+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=immense-tor-49304.herokuapp.com request_id=e2d01455-f352-4e6f-8625-efb05c8ab565 fwd="203.233.123.43" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Any idea? Thank in advance

Comment: Have you checked `heroku logs`?

Comment: Error: Cannot find module '/app/index.js'